# Is $c$ (as in $y=mx+c$) the $x$ or $y$ intercept?

Tags: functions

In $y=5x+6$, is the $6$ the $y$-intercept or the $x$-intercept? I can't remember and need to know for revision.

Answer (score 1):

$y$-interscepts happen when $x = 0$, since that's where all points on the $y$-axis lie. If we insert this, we get
$$
y = 5\cdot 0 + 6 = 6
$$
so the so-called *constant term* is the $y$-coordinate of the $y$-intercept.

Usually, $y$-intercepts are the ones that take the least effort to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In line $y=mx+c$, here $c$ is the intercept on $y$-axis...just remind by keeping the fact $c$ is independent of $x$, put $x=0$ on $y$-axis we get $y=c$.

Answer (score 0):

Arthur gives a good logical way of going about it (make sure you understand his answer), but perhaps a pictorial one would help:[image]

It should be clear from the picture that $6$ is the $y$-intercept for $y=5x+6$.

Comment: The first of these plots is rather misleading, because the $y$-axis on it is not at $x=0$, so it is _not_ the $y$-axis the word "$y$-intercept" refers to.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You're right--I guess I just wanted it to be clear from the screenshot that $y=5x+6$ was, in fact, being plotted. I should have mentioned to disregard the first plot or procured the screenshot differently. Good point though.